# 5,3,6,7 are lengths of consecutive sides of a hexagon of equal angles what are the lengths of the other 2 sides

Tags: geometry

In a hexagon with equal angles, the lengths of four consecutive edges are 5, 3, 6 and 7 (in that order). Find the lengths of the remaining two edges

My answer came to be 1 and 8 but i can't check my answer.
This is a question from BMOTC

Answer (score 4):

Hint :

[image]

The red and black triangles are equilateral and each of the $6$ "corner" triangles are also equilateral.

> The lengths of the sides are $5,3,6,7,\color{blue}{1,8}$

Comment: +1 A perfect way of answering this question if you aske me! Hoping it is not a *live* contest, when this could aide cheating.